Computing $\displaystyle\int_{0}^\infty\dfrac{\sin^2x}{x^2}\,\mathrm dx$ using the FT of a wave train
Say we've got a wave train like so
$$f(t)=
\left\{\begin{aligned}
&e^{i\omega_0 t},\enspace |t|<T\\
& 0,\!\qquad |t|>T
\end{aligned}\right. $$
If we define the FT of a function like
$$\hat f(\omega)\equiv\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{-i\omega t}\,\mathrm dt\ ,$$
then the FT of our wave train is, briefly,
$$\hat f(\omega)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-T}^Te^{i(\omega_0-\omega)t}\,\mathrm dt=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\dfrac{e^{i(\omega_0-\omega)T}-e^{-i(\omega_0-\omega)T}}{i(\omega_0-\omega)}=\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}}\dfrac{\sin[(\omega_0-\omega)T]}{\omega_0-\omega}.$$
In view that its FT has the form $\sin(x)/x$, we can maybe exploit Parseval's identity, in order to calculate the desired integral.
It can be derived pretty straightforward and assuming the necessary conditions:
$$\begin{aligned}
\color{blue}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\Phi(t)|^2\,\mathrm dt}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi(t)\Phi^\ast(t)\,\mathrm dt&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left[\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\hat \Phi(\omega)e^{i\omega t}\,\mathrm d\omega\right]\cdot\left[ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat \Phi^\ast(\omega')e^{-i\omega' t}\,\mathrm d\omega'\right]\,\mathrm dt\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat \Phi(\omega) \hat \Phi^\ast(\omega') \left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i(\omega-\omega') t}\,\mathrm dt\right]\,\mathrm d\omega\,\mathrm d\omega'\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat \Phi^\ast(\omega')\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat \Phi(\omega) \delta(\omega-\omega')\,\mathrm d\omega\right]\,\mathrm d\omega'\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat \Phi(\omega')\hat \Phi^\ast(\omega')\,\mathrm d\omega'\color{blue}{=\dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty |\hat \Phi(\omega')|^2\,\mathrm d\omega'}
\end{aligned}$$
Now let's apply this result to our case:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(t)|^2\,\mathrm dt=\int_{-T}^T |e^{i\omega_0 t}|^2\,\mathrm dt=2T&\overset{!}{=}\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}}\dfrac{\sin[(\omega_0-\omega)T]}{\omega_0-\omega}\right)^2\,\mathrm d\omega\\
&=\dfrac{T^2}{\pi^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{\sin^2[(\omega_0-\omega)T]}{(\omega_0-\omega)^2T^2}\,\mathrm d\omega\\
&\overset{x=(\omega_0-\omega)T}{=}\dfrac{T^2}{\pi^2}\int_{\infty}^{-\infty} \dfrac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}\,\dfrac{-\mathrm dx}{T}\\
&=\dfrac{T}{\pi^2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}\,\mathrm dx=\dfrac{2T}{\pi^2}\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}\,\mathrm dx
\end{aligned}$$
And therefore we would get that
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}\,\mathrm dx=\pi^2,$$
but the result is actually $\pi/2$. What's the problem here? Maybe it has to do with the factor in front of the inverse transform?

The integral where you proved Parseval's theorem did not evaluate properly. You incorrectly stated $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i(\omega-\omega')t}dt= \delta(\omega-\omega')$$ when it should be $2\pi\cdot\delta(\omega-\omega')$. This result is independent of Fourier transform convention.

Thank you, I didn't notice! So basically if the convention has a $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$
factor both transform and inverse wear it, and if it has a $1/2\pi$
factor, then only the inverse, right?
